# Visual Studio reference mixup in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, reporting-services, webforms

I'm currently in the process of incorporating reporting services using webforms into our web application (MVC). Having issues with some of the references to ReportViewer in my existing project, I created a new project and found that the default references for ReportViewer were working fine and was able to create a control for it in an aspx page. It seems that my existing project has an updated ReportViewer with faulty references. With this in mind, I took the fresh project and used nuget to update the default ReportViewer assemblies in an attempt to recreate the issue.

The issue persisted, so I tried uninstalling the update on the fresh project. After carefully restoring the web.config and aspx file to their original states, and making sure the references were restored as well, I tried adding a new ReportViewer to what should have been a fresh project after the uninstall. This produced the error in the preview pane:

"Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Version 14.0.0.0 was the updated version, while version 12.0.0.0 is the default and currently active version. No where in my code do I have 14.0.0.0 referenced anymore, nor is it referenced in the csproj file or packages.

Is there some place that I might have missed cleaning up after I uninstalled the update?

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if one of your project folders you have Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll version 14.0 (if its there , even if you reference to version 12.0 visual studio will use the "nearset" dll)

2.if previous suggestion does not help, Edit your .csproj files with notepad or notepad++ and find the reference there.

Comment: I have looked in the whole solution directory, and the only references to it are the bin/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll, which is listed as 12.0, and the .csproj file which has a single reference to the 12.0 assembly. The aspx file itself also references 12.0, so I'm not sure where it's still getting 14.0 from.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, ... is listed in the GAC. Check with

```
gacutil -l
```

If it is not listed there, you can load the components as follows:

```
cd "<project-packages-path>\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.1000.523\lib\net40"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.resources.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.resources.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.resources.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign.resources.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.resources.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll"
gacutil -i "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll"
```

You might need to restart Visual Studio in order to see the new components.